# Making a calculated column SQL from 2 tables that result lives in a third

Tags: mysql, sql-server, t-sql

TABLE 1: `EventBill(EstTotal)`

Table 2: `OperatingCost(EmpCost)`

Table 3: `Venue(VenueRate)`

I have these three tables and I am trying to get them to work together so that the `EstTotal` is calculated from the other two variables :

```
ALTER TABLE EventBill
SELECT ShiftLength,
       VenueRate 
FROM DesiredStaffLevel,
     Venue
ADD EstTotal AS (ShiftLength * VenueRate)
```

All the readings and texts I'm looking at say this works for a single column. Am I missing something to do this with multiple tables ? Maybe a join ? I'm still not quote fluent on those.

Comment: you need  most probably need a stored procedure for what you are attempting

Answer (score 0):

What you are attempting CANNOT be achieved using a "computed column".

> A computed column is computed from an expression that can use other columns **in the same table**. The expression can be a noncomputed column name, constant, function, and any combination of these connected by one or more operators, **but the expression cannot be a subquery**.

[Kun Cheng (Microsoft SQLCAT)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlcat/2011/11/28/a-computed-column-defined-with-a-user-defined-function-might-impact-query-performance/) **bold** emphasis added